# Multiple views with different heights in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper which has some 10 views in it and each view is of different size (height wise). Everything is working fine. The problem is, the smaller views are getting padded(height) to make their height equal to the largest view. 
Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Thx!
Rahul.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Ok. I searched a bit more and found the following solution. Need to set the `android:measureAllChildren` to `false` in the `ViewFlipper`.

Comment: Superb! Nailed it! I always thought this can't be fixed but today I was so stuck that I had to find a solution for ViewFlipper once and for all and found this, Cool!

Comment: Great one! Helped me save a lot of time.